# Read and extract multiple PDF's from multiple folders using python

Tags: python, pdf, text

I have a folder named as SOURCE. This SOURCE folder has multiple Folders- A, B, C, D,E, F, G, H. All these folders have multiple PDF files. I want to read a single pdf file from All- One from A, One from B, One from C, One from D, till H. So All in all from 8 folders, I want to read the first pdf file and extract the text data from it.
To extract text data from 1pdf is fine, but how do I extract text data from multiple pdfs?
here's my code to extract a text data for a single pdf.

```
from pdfminer.layout import LAParams, LTTextBox
from pdfminer.pdfpage import PDFPage
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFResourceManager
from pdfminer.pdfinterp import PDFPageInterpreter
from pdfminer.converter import PDFPageAggregator
from pdfminer.converter import TextConverter
import io
import glob as g

resource_manager = PDFResourceManager()
fake_file_handle = io.StringIO()
converter = TextConverter(resource_manager, fake_file_handle, laparams=LAParams())
page_interpreter = PDFPageInterpreter(resource_manager, converter)


with open('F:/technophile/Proj/SOURCE/A/abc.pdf', 'rb') as fh:

    for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
        page_interpreter.process_page(page)

    text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()

# close open handles
converter.close()
fake_file_handle.close()

print(text)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you could try something like this :

```
# your code

import os

folder = ['A','B','C','D','E','F','G','H']
allyourpdf = []


for fold in folder:
    allyourfiles = os.listdir(fold)
    firstpdf = ""
    for i in allyourfiles:
        if '.pdf' in i:
            firstpdf = i
            break

    with open('F:/technophile/Proj/SOURCE/'+fold+firstpdf, 'rb') as fh:

        for page in PDFPage.get_pages(fh, caching=True, check_extractable=True):
            page_interpreter.process_page(page)

        text = fake_file_handle.getvalue()
        allyourpdf.append(text)

# your code
```

I think it should work

Comment: Thanks for your prompt reply! in the with open code block,  abc.pdf would give an error. because not all folders contain abc.pdf. I wanted to select 1st pdf file from each folder

Comment: @technophile_3 I just modified my answer, now it find the first pdf file on each folder and it treats it

Comment: I was still getting an OSError because of os.listdir(), made a few tweaks and now your solution works fine! thanks alot!

Comment: Suppose if I would like to read all files from all folder using the same code, how can I make it happen?